# How do I get a user's presence by the email address with Microsoft graph toolkit?

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

In Teams, SharePoint, and Outlook, we see all users' presence. 
Why can't we get it easily with graph toolkit? 
How do I get a user's presence by the email address with the Microsoft graph toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

mgt-people / mgt-person / mgt-person-card are planned to have presence added to the next release (v1.3). [Here is the pr](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/pull/399) that introduced the changes. We are planning on releasing this package by next week. You can try it out with the release candidate by installing @microsoft/mgt@v1.3.0-rc.1

Once you have the release candidate. You can run the project with `npm start` and see the mgt-person component with presence added as below. This is the html that enables this feature: `<mgt-person person-query="me" view="twoLines" person-card="hover" show-presence></mgt-person>`

[image]

Comment: Thank you looking forward to this

Comment: Hey @OferGal, v1.3.0 is published! :)